# derivate of a function of 2 variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, frechet-derivative

Can someone explain this to me : 
($f$ is a differentiable function)
why is $\frac{d}{dt} f(2,t) = ∇f(2,t) \cdot (0,1)$?

This reminds me of the formula of directional derivate but it's not the same.

I also would like to see a demonstration of this formula (I didn't know it before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g(t)=(2,t)$. Then $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}f(2,t)=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(f\circ g)(t)$. But then you can apply the chain rule:$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(f\circ g)(t)=f'\bigl(g(t)\bigr)\bigl(g'(t)\bigr).$$But $g'(t)=(0,1)$ and so$$f'\bigl(g(t)\bigr)\bigl(g'(t)\bigr)=f'\bigl((2,t)\bigr)\bigl((0,1)\bigr)=\nabla f(2,t).(0,1).$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.